# Xbee : Some device don't receive Broadcast

Tags: xbee

I use *Xbee series 1* and *Arduino Uno* to control them. I put a code that analyse Rx and than send to another to get the "coordinator". All data are send in API mode to get all information.

I have a network of Xbee in my office (one per room) and I use another Xbee that broadcast some data. but sometimes, the Xbee in the same room can't send data instead of some that are in other room. The problem is that I need the information of all device in my field of area.

Is it possible that the fact the Arduino must send some data from other Xbee to the coordinator may cause him not to send the data he receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the buffer of an Xbee is limited but in my case, the Xbee receive 3 api message and than transfert a new message to the end one which is connected to a computer.

The problem is that i needed to slow down the speed of transmission due to the overflow of buffer.

My solution was sending the message after X sec where X depends on the RSSI so the channel was free and I see that every Xbee can now send what they see.

If someone is on the same case, he can reply on this to have my help